# Array assignment using multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a uniform 2D coordinate grid stored in a numpy array.  The values of this array are assigned by a function that looks roughly like the following:

```
def update_grid(grid):
    n, m = grid.shape
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            #assignment
```

Calling this function takes 5-10 seconds for a 100x100 grid, and it needs to be called several hundred times during the execution of my main program.  This function is the rate limiting step in my program, so I want to reduce the process time as much as possible.

I believe that the assignment expression inside can be split up in a manner which accommodates multiprocessing.  The value at each gridpoint is independent of the others, so the assignments can be split something like this:

```
def update_grid(grid):
    n, m = grid.shape
    for i in range (n):
        for j in range (m):
            p = Process(target=#assignment)
            p.start()
```

So my questions are:

1. Does the above loop structure ensure each process will only operate
   on a single gridpoint?  Do I need anything else to allow each
   process to write to the same array, even if they're writing to
   different placing in that array?
2. The assignment expression requires a set of parameters.  These are
   constant, but each process will be reading at the same time.  Is this okay?
3. To explicitly write the code I've structured above, I would need to
   define my assignment expression as another function inside of
   update_grid, correct?
4. Is this actually worthwhile?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I still haven't figured out how to speed up the assignment, but I was able to avoid the problem by changing my main program.  It no longer needs to update the entire grid with each iteration, and instead tracks changes and only updates what has changed.  This cut the execution time of my program down from an hour to less than a minute.

Comment: Can't you do the assignment for multiple `n` and `m` at 'once'?  Array assignments are faster than multiprocessing.

Comment: I thought that's what I was trying to do.  How can I do simultaneous assignments without multiprocessing?  Here I should probably note that the assignment expression depends on n and m.

Comment: Is it not possible to do your assignment solely (or a major part of it) using the functionality provided by `numpy` itself, rather than indexing explicitly? If possible, that would make your work much faster without having to use `multiprocessing` at all.